# Strange Azure SQL password validation error

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having some trouble understanding SQL Azure password validation (in local SQL it works, just not CREATE USER command, but CREATE LOGIN command). Anyway this is user creation statement:

This one works:

```
CREATE USER [test1] WITH PASSWORD = 'testicus2019!'
```

This one failes with *"Msg 40632, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
Password validation failed. The password does not meet policy requirements because it is not complex enough."*:

```
CREATE USER [test_1] WITH PASSWORD = 'testicus2019!'
```

I understand that passwords must not contain usernames, but this is not the case in any of the statements. Does SQL on Azure break usernames with underscore in it? Where could I find such information?

As mentioned the second case works with local SQL, just using `CREATE LOGIN` command.

`print @@version` on Azure SQL returns "12.0.2000.8", if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned correctly here ***'Passwords cannot contain single quotes, or the login_name.'***.

So there is a catch in your case.

In the first statement, the username is entire ***'test1'*** which cannot be exactly found in password ***'testicus2019!'***, so it would allow us to create it.
However in 2nd statement, the username is anything before or after ***underscore***. In your case ***'test_1'*** is checked just for ***'test'*** in password ***'testicus2019!'***.

As another example, if we try creating ***'[test_demo]'*** user with any of passwords ***'testicus2019!' or 'demoicus2019!'***, it would not work. ***However if creating a password like 'password2019!', then it will work.***

Comment: You say "However in 2nd statement, the username is anything before or after underscore.". Is this information available anywhere, that "username is anything before or after underscore". Is this somehow related to the fact, that underscore is used to denote "any character" when building SELECT queries (e.g. "test_1" finds "testa1" and "testb1").

Comment: Underscore is currently just splitting up the character into 2, and then checking the passwords against 'test'. In Select queries it just ignored the '_' and searches. There is currently no documentation also available that states this behavior, hence I reached out to internal product team to check on the same.